# SVN over VPN on Fedora 10

Tags: vpn, svn

I would like to be able to pull changes on a remote server from an SVN server on a local development box. The SVN port is closed to the WAN but available via our LAN and we have a VPN setup locally.

Is it difficult to setup the remote server to use VPN to connect to the remote SVN server and update code? If possible, how/where can I find out how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is the vpn server available to the WAN? If it is you just need to add the remote server to the VPN, add a couple of iptables rules to redirect the traffic to svn server and them access the svn server using the vpn server ip. (if the svn server is also on the vpn, you don't need the iptables rules, just access it through the vpn ip).
If this isn't enough you need to give a little more info (which VPN server are you using, network topology, etc..).